# OpenGL program works in GL 3.x but not 4.x

Tags: visual-studio-2010, opengl, hardware

To preface this question, I am new to openGL and Visual Studio, so I may be missing something rather obvious. I am following an openGL tutorial that's supposed to set up a basic window that displays information about the version of openGL you are using.

[Tutorial](http://openglbook.com/the-book/chapter-1-getting-started/) | 
[Setup](http://openglbook.com/setting-up-opengl-glew-and-freeglut-in-visual-c/)

For reference, I am running VS2010 on 64-bit Windows 7 on an NVidia GTX670m. When I specify that the boilerplate program run in openGL v3.x. It runs just fine. When I specify that it run in v4.x. It crashes with the following output (question to continue after):

```
'Engine.exe': Loaded 'D:\Engine\Engine\Release\Engine.exe', Symbols loaded.
'Engine.exe': Loaded 'C:\Windows\SysWOW64\ntdll.dll', Symbols loaded (source information stripped).
'Engine.exe': Loaded 'C:\Windows\SysWOW64\kernel32.dll', Symbols loaded (source information stripped).
'Engine.exe': Loaded 'C:\Windows\SysWOW64\KernelBase.dll', Symbols loaded (source information stripped).
'Engine.exe': Loaded 'C:\Windows\SysWOW64\freeglut.dll', Binary was not built with debug information.
'Engine.exe': Loaded 'C:\Windows\SysWOW64\user32.dll', Symbols loaded (source information stripped).
'Engine.exe': Loaded 'C:\Windows\SysWOW64\gdi32.dll', Symbols loaded (source information stripped).
'Engine.exe': Loaded 'C:\Windows\SysWOW64\lpk.dll', Symbols loaded (source information stripped).
'Engine.exe': Loaded 'C:\Windows\SysWOW64\usp10.dll', Symbols loaded (source information stripped).
'Engine.exe': Loaded 'C:\Windows\SysWOW64\msvcrt.dll', Symbols loaded (source information stripped).
'Engine.exe': Loaded 'C:\Windows\SysWOW64\advapi32.dll', Symbols loaded (source information stripped).
'Engine.exe': Loaded 'C:\Windows\SysWOW64\sechost.dll', Symbols loaded (source information stripped).
'Engine.exe': Loaded 'C:\Windows\SysWOW64\rpcrt4.dll', Symbols loaded (source information stripped).
'Engine.exe': Loaded 'C:\Windows\SysWOW64\sspicli.dll', Symbols loaded (source information stripped).
'Engine.exe': Loaded 'C:\Windows\SysWOW64\cryptbase.dll', Symbols loaded (source information stripped).
'Engine.exe': Loaded 'C:\Windows\SysWOW64\opengl32.dll', Symbols loaded (source information stripped).
'Engine.exe': Loaded 'C:\Windows\SysWOW64\glu32.dll', Symbols loaded (source information stripped).
'Engine.exe': Loaded 'C:\Windows\SysWOW64\ddraw.dll', Symbols loaded (source information stripped).
'Engine.exe': Loaded 'C:\Windows\SysWOW64\dciman32.dll', Symbols loaded (source information stripped).
'Engine.exe': Loaded 'C:\Windows\SysWOW64\setupapi.dll', Symbols loaded (source information stripped).
'Engine.exe': Loaded 'C:\Windows\SysWOW64\cfgmgr32.dll', Symbols loaded (source information stripped).
'Engine.exe': Loaded 'C:\Windows\SysWOW64\oleaut32.dll', Symbols loaded (source information stripped).
'Engine.exe': Loaded 'C:\Windows\SysWOW64\ole32.dll', Symbols loaded.
'Engine.exe': Loaded 'C:\Windows\SysWOW64\devobj.dll', Symbols loaded (source information stripped).
'Engine.exe': Loaded 'C:\Windows\SysWOW64\dwmapi.dll', Symbols loaded (source information stripped).
'Engine.exe': Loaded 'C:\Windows\SysWOW64\winmm.dll', Symbols loaded (source information stripped).
'Engine.exe': Loaded 'C:\Windows\SysWOW64\msvcr100.dll', Symbols loaded (source information stripped).
'Engine.exe': Loaded 'C:\Windows\SysWOW64\imm32.dll', Symbols loaded (source information stripped).
'Engine.exe': Loaded 'C:\Windows\SysWOW64\msctf.dll', Symbols loaded (source information stripped).
'Engine.exe': Loaded 'C:\Windows\SysWOW64\nvinit.dll', Cannot find or open the PDB file
'Engine.exe': Loaded 'C:\Windows\SysWOW64\uxtheme.dll', Symbols loaded (source information stripped).
'Engine.exe': Loaded 'C:\Program Files (x86)\Common Files\Spigot\Search Settings\wth159.dll', Cannot find or open the PDB file
'Engine.exe': Loaded 'C:\Windows\SysWOW64\psapi.dll', Symbols loaded (source information stripped).
'Engine.exe': Loaded 'C:\Windows\SysWOW64\ig7icd32.dll', Cannot find or open the PDB file
'Engine.exe': Loaded 'C:\Windows\SysWOW64\version.dll', Symbols loaded (source information stripped).
'Engine.exe': Unloaded 'C:\Windows\SysWOW64\version.dll'
The program '[7332] Engine.exe: Native' has exited with code 1 (0x1).
```

In googling this problem, I saw some people recommend pulling symbols from the MS server in the debug menu and turning off the option to treat warnings as errors. I tried both but the program still crashed. Even if it didn't, I feel like I should still investigate the cause.

**Assumption:** NVidia lists the GTX 670 as supporting openGL 4.x. It does not explicitly say the 670m is supported, but I am assuming that if the regular 670 is - that mobile version is.

**Question:** If the program works fine with openGL v3.x and my hardware should support openGL v4.x, what is causing my program to crash?

Comment: 670m supports OpenGL 4.1. Sometimes there is a discrepancy so don't always assume. As per this issue can we see some of the code to make sure the GL4 extensions are correctly loaded?

Comment: You're using Visual Studio. Did you try to debug the application to see exactly where it crashes?

Comment: @Jesus Ramos, where did you find that documented? I tried looking for mobile specifics specs but I guess I looked in the wrong place. Nicol Bolas I'm no debugging master, but I'm trying to now. I'll see if I come up with anything.

Comment: @Nicol Bolas So in the code snipped below I put a breakpoint on the assignment and the if statement. glutCreateWindow fails if it is an int < 1. When I test this with openGL 3, the function returns a 1 to WindowHandle and program executes correctly. In openGL 4, the program crashes during the call to glutCreateWindow

    WindowHandle = glutCreateWindow(WINDOW_TITLE_PREFIX);

 if(WindowHandle < 1){
  fprintf(stderr, "ERROR: Could not create a new rendering window.\n");
  exit(EXIT_FAILURE);
 }
 
I'm still trying to search for the answer, but I'm at a loss.

Comment: My suggestion is to use GLEW to initialize GL4 extensions just in case that is causing the failure, also make sure your OpenGL version is set to 4.1 or 4.0.

Comment: It would be nice if you could copy your main initialization code as an edit to the question.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your program didn't crash.  Conditions in some of the logic may not have been met, causing a different branch to run, but it did run to completion.

None of the output you posted has any relation to your "problem" except the very last line, which suggests that the code entered a branch ending in `ExitProcess(1)` or `return EXIT_FAILURE`.

Answer (score 0):

Thanks to everyone for their help. I ended up running this on another machine and did not run into a problem. Either I something is wrong with my laptop's specs or with freeglut